# Serialization: DataMember attribute in overridden attributes

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following code snippet...

```
public MyBaseClass
{
    ...
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Rectangle MyRectangle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    ....
}

public MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    ...
    [DataMember] // Is that necessary?
    public override Rectangle MyRectangle
    {
        get { return base.MyRectangle; }
        set {
            ...
            base.MyRectangle = value;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

... I'm wondering whether or not `[DataMember]` should be also declared for `MyDerivedClass.MyRectangle`? Thanks.

Comment: Id imagine so as you've overridden the property, so I'd have expected that to override it's attributes

Comment: If it isn't required but runs with it anyway, I don't think it would hurt anything to have it. But I imagine it is required. You probably also need a `[KnownType(typeof(MyDerivedClass))]` declaration as a class attribute on `MyBaseClass`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on the usage yo want to make of these attributes. I've encountered a scenario where I used these attributes for serialization with **ProtoBuf**. Everything was working fine without the DataMember attribute on the overridden property. Then we decided to also support serialization with **JSON** format. Then the attribute was mandatory, and as said hawkee it did not impact the existing behavior.